# Send an email with SendGrid and PHP using the PHP SDK

Tags: php, sendgrid

After severals hours of research, I looking for some help.

I would like to use the SendGrid API to send my email with PHP using the PHP SDK found here https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php.

Actually, the code I have is the following:

require("sendgrid/sendgrid-php.php");

```
$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail(); 
$email->setFrom("info@test.org", "Example User");
$email->setSubject("Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun");
$email->addTo("send@gmail.com", "Example User");
$email->addContent("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");
$email->addContent("text/html", "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP</strong>");
$sendgrid = new \SendGrid(getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY'));
try {
    $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
    print_r($response->headers());
    print $response->body() . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
```

I also have the API key in the required `.env` file. I simply named it `.env`. I don't know if it's correct at this point.

The content of this file is the following:

```
export SENDGRID_API_KEY='SG.xxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

When I test the page, I have the following error:

```
401 Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized [1] => Server: nginx [2] => Date: Tue, 03 Sep 2019 23:44:21 GMT [3] => Content-Type: application/json [4] => Content-Length: 88 [5] => Connection: keep-alive [6] => Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sendgrid.api-docs.io [7] => Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST [8] => Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl [9] => Access-Control-Max-Age: 600 [10] => X-No-CORS-Reason: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html [11] => [12] => ) {"errors":[{"message":"Permission denied, wrong credentials","field":null,"help":null}]}
```

What I'm doing wrong please ?

I red the documentation but can't find what the point causing the error.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Are you using pure php or a framework like `Laravel`? did you install `vulcas/dotenv` and `sendgrid-php` packages with composer?

Comment: Hello, I'm using pure PHP. And I don't install Vulcan/dotenv or the package with Composer.